# Azure API Management - Export results to CSV, XLS or XLSX

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I was trying to understand if there is any feature available that would allow you to export the API query results to formats such as csv, xls, etc. But i did not find it. So i wonder if i am missing something, but the requirement would be to be able to easily export the results of a given query that i execute against my API hosted in API Management. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only /reports API support returning results in format other than JSON and only in CSV.

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding from it. I am bit surprised to be honest, since it could be a feature available on API Management, through the transformation policies. But anyway, apparently it is not available.